# Android NDK application stops unexpectedly

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-emulator, strace, ndk-build

I am using android studio. I have downloaded and installed Android NDK by following the instructions given in [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#new-project).

The application runs on the emulator perfectly. I have downloaded the strace for android from [here](https://github.com/android/platform_external_strace).

The problem is that when I give the path of Android.mk file in the ndk build and then `Synchronize`, `Build` and `Run` the application it shows notification that "Application is stopped".

This happens both on the device and emulator.

Any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: Please provide the relevant log details

Comment: I have checked event log. it does not show any thing like error or exception. shall i post the images here?

Comment: What images? If you see absolutely no error, I suggest you try to add log lines from the beginning of you app to locate the line or range that causes the problem. Since it is an NDK project, put extra notice to loading of the shared object

Comment: Thank you so much. There was an error in the `MainActivity.java`. Actually it was looking for `native-library` and there was no any file in the `cpp` folder with the name `native-library` due to which application was stopping.